# Installing IIS Manager Permissions on IIS 8.5 Win 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows, iis, iis-8.5

I have published a web service on my default site in my local machine. Now I want to allow access to a windows user to this web service.

I have read below documentation:[enter link description here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/549c2754-8f30-4ac2-9407-47d6abadd3bb)

There it is said to go to IIS Manager Permissions on features view in default web site.

The problem is that in my IIS, the "IIS Manager Permissions" feature is not showing.

Do I have to install something of windows features related to IIS? If so, which features?

Comment: That’s only available on Windows Server, so you cannot use Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft designs IIS in a way that only Windows Server ships with the necessary bits (you can check relevant articles once again to see that they only show Windows Server screenshots).

Thus, in your case, you cannot use Windows 8.1, but the relevant Windows Server (like Windows Server 2012 R2 or 2016).